# How to style a buttons in material-ui

Tags: material-ui

Hi I want to style three buttons with different colors but When those buttons are disabled the custom style I've added at the beginning overrides the default style disabledTextColor, which adds a default fade and transparency value, so users can see that the button is disabled. How can style the disabled state or which should be the correct way to style the labelStyle and/or disabledTextColor? Here is an example

```
const style = {
      labelStyle: {
        color: 'red;
      }
    }

<FlatButton
        label='Mit Linkedin anmelden'
        labelPosition='after'
        icon={<LinkedinIcon />}
        onClick={() => Meteor.loginWithLinkedin()}
        disabled={true}
        labelStyle={style.labelStyle}
      />
    </div>
    <div className='mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col'>
      <FlatButton
          label='Mit Google anmelden'
          labelPosition='after'
          icon={<GoogleIcon />}
          onClick={() => Meteor.loginWithGoogle()}
          disabled={true}
          labelStyle={style.labelStyle}
        />
    </div>
```

in this case the button always stays red even though the disabled state in True

Comment: Hi there! We'll need some more information from you in order to provide a useful answer. It seems you're saying that Material's `disabled` button styling is overriding your custom styles, but it's unclear what styles or effects you're trying to apply, and how you're accomplishing it. Do you think you could clarify what you're trying to do, and include a sample of your _relevant_ code? Thanks Lido! Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @JacobFord thanks for your answer. I've just added more details, Hope you can help me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a little wrapper component around FlatButton that conditionally fades the labelStyle when the button is disabled.

```
const CustomFlatButton = (props) => (
  <FlatButton
    {...props}
    labelStyle={{ ...props.labelStyle, opacity: props.disabled ? 0.3 : 1 }}
    />
);
```

...

```
<CustomFlatButton label="Disabled Red" style={{ color: 'red' }} disabled />
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6rads3tt/2/

Comment: Hi @jeff thanks for your answer that looks like a good idea but how could I make it more scalable? Because these would be for three different buttons with three different styles for textColor and disabledTextColor. Do I have to make a custom theme for each of one of them and all the three of them have to be wrapped in the muitheme component?

Comment: Hi @LidoFernandez, I updated my answer with a better solution. Hope you find it useful!

Comment: That looks genius! Thanks @Jeff-McCloud